# FTP Passive Mode doesn't upload anything (Java)

Tags: java, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file on a FTP server using the code

```
 try {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(host);
        int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            boolean login = ftpClient.login(user, password);
            if (login) {
                File localFile = new File(fileName);
                InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(localFile);
                ftpClient.appendFile("/folder/output.txt", inputStream);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("FTP client received network error");
    }
```

However, it doesn't upload anything on the FTP server, if i remove the `ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();`
line, it uploads an empty output.txt file. Thanks for anyone that will help.

Comment: Have you already tried to upload a file to that server using another FTP client? Have you tried uploading a file to another FTP server? When using passive FTP, the server must be configured to accept new connections to non-privileged ports (although the server itself announces the port to the client, a firewall protecting the FTP server might not track the FTP session, thus rejecting the data connection). When using active FTP, the server tries to open a new connection to the client, which fails, if the client firewall is not configured to allow that.